# Why is a row, in a table with border radius, overlapping the rounded corners in IE11?

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I created a table with border-radius. But when checking this in IE11 it shows as if the borders aren't rounded. If I up the value of the border and border-radius, it shows clearly that the row is overlapping the table border.

I have tried the meta tag `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` and changed the “Compatibility View” settings. but without avail.

```css
th {
  background-color: #3771c9;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 5px solid red;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="size-table__table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--header">
        <th class="size-row__header">test1</th>
        <th class="size-row__header">test2</th>
        <th class="size-row__header">test3</th>
        <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
        <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
      </tr>


      <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">70</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R14</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
      </tr>


      <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">65</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R15</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
        <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
      </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have this fiddle which shows my problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/b05vyhxo/1/

Check that Chrome shows a rounded table and notice on IE11 the border being overlapped. I can probably solve this by making my first and the last row having a border. But I'm also eager to know why this isn't working, especially since I couldn't find any solution to keep the border on the table, which seems normal to be done, even for IE11.

**UPDATE**

Thanks G-cyr running IE11 for helping me. Your solution fixed this.

adding:

```
table {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
```

did the trick to show rounded corners on IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code with IE 11 and Microsoft Edge browser and I am able to reproduce the problem. It can be possible that it is some kind of bug or it is IE/Edge default behavior. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a workaround, I think we could set the border-radius property for the cells in the four corners, code as below:

```
<style>
    th {
        background-color: #3771c9;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 5px 2px;
        word-break: break-all;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    table {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 5px solid red;
        table-layout: fixed;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table class="size-table__table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--header">
            <th class="size-row__header" style="border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px">test1</th>
            <th class="size-row__header">test2</th>
            <th class="size-row__header">test3</th>
            <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
            <th class="size-row__header" style="border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px">test4</th>
        </tr>


        <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">70</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R14</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
            <td class="size-row__data" style="border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 40px"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">65</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R15</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
            <td class="size-row__data" style="border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 0px"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result in IE browser as below:

[image]

Edit:

You could also use the following CSS style:

```
<style>
    th {
        background-color: #3771c9;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 5px 2px;
        word-break: break-all;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    table {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 5px solid red;
        table-layout: fixed;
        text-align: center;
    }
        table tr:first-child th:first-child {
            border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        table tr:first-child th:last-child {
            border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
        }

        table tr:last-child td:first-child {
            border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
        }
        table tr:last-child td:last-child {
            border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: I did a wrong edit here I thought it was my post and thought I uploaded the wrong image. But its the image of Zhi who commented on my problem. I'm surprised I could edit others' comments, pls cancel the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper to avoid this buggy behavior or reset `display` on `table` and `tbody` here in your case since `thead` and `tfoot` are not used:

```css
th {
  background-color: #3771c9;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display:block;
}

tbody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th, td {padding:0 22px;}/* push away from border-radius */
```

```html
<table class="size-table__table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--header">
      <th class="size-row__header">test1</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test2</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test3</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
    </tr>


    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">70</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R14</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">65</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R15</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> if <code>tbody</code> is not written in the HTML code, the browser generates it anyway. <i>(=> browsers always try as possible to fix code miswritten or when tags are missing)</i>. Demo below without the tbody tag in the code but still here.</p>
<table class="size-table__table"> 
    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--header">
      <th class="size-row__header">test1</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test2</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test3</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
      <th class="size-row__header">test4</th>
    </tr>


    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">70</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R14</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="size-table__size-row size-row size-row--data">
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">185</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">65</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">R15</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">88</a></td>
      <td class="size-row__data"><a class="size-row__link" href="#">T</a></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

*no need to add a screen, trust my pseudo ;)*